# Adobe Flex/Actionscript event handling order

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, adobe

As simply as possible, I am trying to find out if events are guaranteed to be handled in the order they are dispatched.  Let's say I have the following, simple code:

```
private function handler1(e:Event):void { .. processing ..}
private function handler2(e:Event):void { .. processing ..}
private function handler3(e:Event):void { .. processing ..}

<SomeComponent myEvent1="handler1(event)" myEvent2="handler2(event)" myEvent3="handler3(event)" ... />
```

If somewhere in my application (either from within the component itself or another place with the component instantiated), if I dispatch those events in the order of 1, 2, 3, like:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('myEvent1'));
dispatchEvent(new Event('myEvent2'));
dispatchEvent(new Event('myEvent3'));
```

Are those handlers guaranteed to fire in the same order (i.e., handler1, handler2, handler3)...?  Anything I search the internet (read: Google) for concerning "adobe event processing order" or anything similar just refers to the event lifecycle.  I cannot find anything on this specific nuiance though.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

--Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two events are dispatched one after another as shown in your code, the second event will be dispatched only after all handlers of the first event is executed and the `dispatchEvent` method is returned.

```
private function handler_1(e:Event):void {}
private function handler_2(e:Event):void {}

a.addEventListener(Event.TYPE_1, handler_1);
a.addEventListener(Event.TYPE_2, handler_2);

//Different events:
//handler_1 will be called before handler_2
a.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.TYPE_1));
a.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.TYPE_2));
```

But if you've registered two listeners registered with same priority for an event, they are processed in the order in which they were added.

```
private function handler_1(e:Event):void {}
private function handler_2(e:Event):void {}

a.addEventListener(Event.TYPE_1, handler_1);
a.addEventListener(Event.TYPE_1, handler_2);

/*
  Same event, same priority:
  Called based on the order in which they were added;
  Hence handler_1 is called first.
*/
a.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.TYPE_1));
```

You can use the [priority](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) parameter of the `addEventListener` method to enforce the order:

```
a.addEventListener(Event.TYPE_1, handler_1, false, 0);
a.addEventListener(Event.TYPE_1, handler_2, false, 1);//higher priority

/*
  handler_2 will be invoked before handler_1 
*/
a.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.TYPE_1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ditto Robert Bak's response. If you absolutely -need- to make this work for whatever reason, though, you could tag the events with a number that increments by one each time, have your listeners merely store them in a central queue of some kind, then sort them according to the index you've assigned. Probably more work than it's worth though.

Answer (score 0):

They usually do, but there's no guarantee, so you shouldn't assume they will.

Comment: I get this conflicting answer at the Adobe forum:  http://forums.adobe.com/thread/739912?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

If God had meant us to know the order in which events will occur, he wouldn't have given us callLater()

;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the event cycle starts when a event dispatch happens, goes to its parent, and then up the UI hierarchy through other parents from where it goes back down to through its children. Below is a diagram that illustrates the event lifecycle in Flex:

[image: Flex event lifecycle]

Events go through different phases, but some events can be restricted from certain phases. When creating a new event, you can prevent the event from bubbling up during the bubbling phase. For more details read [Essential ActionScript 3.0](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526948)
 by Colin Moock.

Events are not triggered or processed in any sequence. They depende on when the event is fired. In Flex, events are asynchronous.